# How can I compartmentalize different sections of website in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

I am working on a website which could be visited my users from different countries. However, I only want to show them country specific content and change things like where navigation takes them based on their country.

For example, Let's say that I have created a website which lists information about different countries like their culture, demographics etc.

The main navigation of the website could be like: `Home`, `Culture`, `Demographics`, `Industries` etc.

Now, if someone visits from the US and clicks on Culture, they should see information about US culture. If someone visits from the UK and clicks on Culture, they should see information about UK culture.

The pages can have different URLs like `the-domain.com/us-culture/` and `the-domain.com/uk-culture` etc. However, when someone from UK clicks on the Culture in the navigation menu they should be sent to `the-domain.com/uk-culture`.

Is it possible to do this in WordPress? I am an absolute beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about multi-website? Then you can share certain plugins and settings but content is different and than just redirect according to country. If you don't want to go that method you can filter content based on country. There are several plugins you can use.

Comment: Thanks Orlando :). Is multi-website a plugin? Will I have to have different domains?

Comment: multi-site is a network of WordPress websites that share the WordPress core but can share additional resources. Here is a guide, https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/ you can user subdomains or regular urls like you wanted.

Comment: WordPress multi-site is built in. You do not need a plugin. But some plugins have issues with multi-site.

Comment: If the sites use different languages, you may like the polylang plugin.

Comment: Thanks @PaulH and @Orlando. :) I will go through through the article to learn more about it. The site will be in English. Only the content will change based on the location of the user. Even the content will stay the same, it is just that people from US will only be able to navigate the `culture-us`. There will be separate pages for different countries focused on culture like `culture-us`, `culture-jp`, `culture-uk` etc.

Comment: It sounds like you need one website and not multi-site with a different menu depending on the culture.

Comment: @PaulH What will a multi-site be useful for? I skimmed through the linked article and it seems to so what I want. Am I missing something?